# 'no main manifest attribute' Gradle didn't create a manifest folder and file?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm following these instructions to create and execute a jar file:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/real-logic/simple-binary-encoding.git
$ ./gradlew
$ cd ./sbe-tool/build/libs
$ wget ftp://ftp.cmegroup.com/SBEFix/NRCert/Templates/templates_FixBinary.xml
$ java -jar -Dsbe.target.language=cpp -Dsbe.keyword.append.token=_ sbe-tool-1.19.0-SNAPSHOT.jar templates_FixBinary.xml
```

Detailed here:

https://mattpearson.github.io/2016/10/07/Decoding-CM-E-MDP-30.html

(the executable generated has a different version from the 4 year old article, so I had to modify the last command to reflect this)

I enter the commands and everything works up until the last:

```
java -jar -Dsbe.target.language=cpp -Dsbe.keyword.append.token=_ sbe-tool-1.19.0-SNAPSHOT.jar templates_FixBinary.xml
```

but I get:

```
no main manifest attribute, in sbe-tool-1.19.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The folder containing the jar file only also contains a sbe-tool-1.19.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar file. There is no manifest folder.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

`MANIFEST.MF` is a file in the structure of the jar (under `resources` in the jar). If the file is present in the .jar then its missing the `Main-class` entry. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html - the jar format is the same as the .zip format for archived files/directories. You should be able to modify the manifest if necessary using this information.